# Возврат аргумента как переменной

Tags: javascript

Почему:

```
var one = 0;
function inputOne(){
  return one = prompt('Input one');
}
```

возвращает без проблем, а если передавать переменную как аргумент:

```
var one = 0;
function input(e){
  return e = prompt('Input one');
}
```

то она только локально внутри функции меняется? В чем разница вызовов?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Разница в том что в первом случае `var one = 0;` у вас определена глобально (во внешнем коде). А значит доступна во всех функциях и во вне их.

А `e` у вас чисто локальная переменная, во вне она не объявлена, значит и недоступна во вне.
Во втором случае e это ссылка, даже если туда передать one то ссылка e будет указывать на one. И если она задаётся в промпт, то это просто ссылка e будет указывать на новое значение, а one при этом не затронется.

То есть в результате prompt создастся новый объект и ссылка e будет указывать на него, в то время как ссылка one из внешнего кода куда ссылалась туда и продолжила ссылаться, на старый объект.

Зато если вы туда передадите сложный объект, то уже внутри него замены произойдут

```js
var one = {one:0};
function input(e){
  return e.one = prompt('Input one');
}

input(one);
console.log(one);
```

Comment: понял. на самом деле не очевидно) спасибо

Comment: @Enity если ответ вам разъяснил ситуацию, отметьте его пожалуйста ответом.